# View Actual Byte Stream Sent by NodeJS GRPC Libraries

Tags: node.js, serialization, grpc

Is there a way to log or view the actual bytestream being sent to the server when using either the [grpc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grpc) or [@grpc/grpc-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@grpc/grpc-js) clients in NodeJS?

I'm working with an opaque GRPC server that accepts my bytes when I stream them, but doesn't do what it's supposed to do.  I'd like to view the actual bytes being sent to the server, as we suspect it's a problem with how the GRPC libraries are serializing 64 bit integers.

The `GRPC_VERBOSITY=debug GRPC_TRACE=tcp,http,api,http2_stream_state` env variables for the native `grpc` module haven't been helpful in this specific case -- they show part of one byte stream, but not the full byte-stream.

Even a "here's the place in the code where the serialization happens" would be useful.

Comment: In the native module, the `api` should be sufficient to see all of the serialized and deserialized messages. What information are you looking for that you're not getting from that?

Comment: @murgatroid99 Thank you for responding -- but I'm not sure what "the api" means in this context.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped. I meant the `api` tracer: the third thing you have in the `GRPC_TRACE` list.

Comment: OK, that's useful @murgatroid99 -- we looked at that output and it seemed like it didn't print the full byte-stream, just a truncated version.  We presumed this was due to limits in the logging. Maybe the problem we're seeing is things are being serialized in a truncated way

Comment: Actually, I think I was wrong. It looks like that doesn't output actual message data.

Answer (score 1):

The `GRPC_VERBOSITY` setting there is correct. If you are using TLS, you can see all of the data that is sent and received with `GRPC_TRACE=secure_endpoint`. If you are using plaintext connections, you can instead see it with `GRPC_TRACE=tcp`. In both cases, you will need to pick the data you are looking for out of the HTTP/2 framing, and it may show compressed messages, which would be essentially impossible to interpret.

Alternatively, if your setup allows it, you may want to try Wireshark. It should be able to handle the HTTP/2 framing for you, and I believe it has plugins to handle gRPC traffic specifically.